# Simple head and tails bot

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, I've been trying to write a simple coinflip script for my discord server. The following error is given: "NameError: name 'result' is not defined" while I tried moving the calculation out of the object, the output I received appeared to be the same value, over and over.

```
elif message.content.startswith(config.prefix + 'coinflip'):
    async def flip():
        result = random.randint(0, 1)
        return
    if result == (1):
        print ('Heads!')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, content = 'Heads!') 
    if result == (0):
        print ('Tails!')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, content = 'Tails!')
```

Comment: check the scope of your `result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott said, result is defined inside the flip function.  I haven't really used async before, but probably this will work for you.

1. Take out the return statement
2. Tab the following lines.

   ```
   elif message.content.startswith(config.prefix + 'coinflip'):
       result = random.randint(0, 1)

       if result == 1:
           print('Heads!')
           await client.send_message(message.channel, content = 'Heads!') 
       else:
           print('Tails!')
           await client.send_message(message.channel, content = 'Tails!')
   ```

Comment: Thanks,  I was having problems inputting text in code format.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is defined *inside* of `flip`, and thus isn't accessible from outside of it.